# React app hosted on s3 unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, npm, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework

I am using servereless to deploy me backend and front end. My front end is using create react app. I believe after I made the following changes

```
<img className="svg-width" src="/img/Icons/photographer-camera.svg" alt="camera icon" />



<img className="svg-width" src="/img/icons/photographer-camera.svg" alt="camera icon" />
```

Where I changed **Icons/** to **icons/** I get the following issue:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

In my s3 bucket I navigate to img/ and verify that my directory is also lowercase for icons.

[image: S3 Directory]

The file in question of the syntax error is `main.977eb738.js` under /static/js/main.977eb738.js of my domain. But when I go to my bucket I don't see that js file. I see

[image: JS Directory in S3]

The code in the file its complaining about is the `index.html` in public/index.html in the create react app boilerplate.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

One more thing to note is this works fine locally and even on mobile. I thought this could be cloudfront caching so I waited a full day and still cannot get to the bottom of this error.

Comment: There is no reason to wait a full day.  Just create a CloudFront [invalidation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) of your entire distribution by specifying `/*` as the path.  Wait for it to finish, and retest.  Also, the `Age` and `X-Cache` response headers are there to give you an idea of what CloudFront is doing.  If `Age` is not present and you see `X-Cache: Miss from Cloudfront` then the object was not in the cache.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue. I tested incognito and the site worked fine in inco after doing a cache invalidation the same way that Michael stated in the first comment. It looks like it is browser caching alongside the Cloudfront caching.

I was able to resolve the issue by **clearing browser cookies/data from the last day**.

Comment: Been busting my head for like a day now wondering why my site came up empty when I tried hosting it, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: I am facing the same problem and clearing cache on my browser does the trick as expected, but how can I fix it on all other customers browsers ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks! This helped me find the problem and `ctrl + shift + r` worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend anyone who is uploading directly to AWS S3 bucket to clear the CloudFront edge cache.

Using AWS CLI this can be done with the folowing line:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOURID --paths "/*"
```

In order to find the CloudFront Distribution Id navigate to cloudFront in AWS console.

Read more here: [Invalidating Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my CloudFront distribution was blocking access to all /static/* files. Creating a CF behavior that whitelisted that path resolved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue. I wasn't using serverless(AWS lambda).
What was happening was that inside my `build/index.html` somehow it was failing at the link's hrefs, and script's src tag. 
So, I had 
`<link href="/static/css/main.866f5359.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">` 
and I changed it to 
`<link href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/fullthrottle-labs-react-task/static/css/main.866f5359.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">`, 
similarly for scripts as well.

So, instead of giving relative paths in `build/index.html`, giving an absolute path did the trick for me.